# Illustrator: rounding corners of paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, maps, corners

I am trying to create a transit map using round corners, both 45deg as well as 90deg angles.

Now, I know I should have used the pen tool initially, but I didnt. I used the line segment tool, then I joined all the individual line segments of the track, and rounded corners using Effects > Stylise > Round corners.

After this only half of the corners were rounded, which I found weird.

In the screenshot I have circled the round corners in blue and the ones I couldn't do in red.

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. After using the line segment tool, I joined the lines using Object > Path > Join. Then applied the Effects > Stylize > Rounded Corners. It seems to be working fine. What version of AI are you using?

Comment: I figured it out right before jooja told me in the answers. It involved anchor points being so close to each other that i thought they were one, but apparently they overlapped. Wherever anchor points overlapped, i couldnt get a round corner ... It gave rise to a new problem though, about how to make sure anchor points dont overlap, which ill post again in another question

Comment: As to your new problem, I have found enabling Smart Guides helps to draw lines and match them up with anchor points.

Comment: yes. but what I was doing was trying to modify line segments. since i have a lot of joins in this, since it is a transit map, i finally decided to use the pen tool, with smart guides on, and draw everything again. which was much faster. thanks though :-)

Answer (score 1):

The old rounding tool was broken, used by the effect, it can not round over a segment and it didnt allways do correct rounds.* So if your curve has 2 overlapping points in that place it will not round. Also if you have 2 separate curves they will also not round.

* The new round has not got this flaw but the new hotfix makes the round broken yet again